# Почему Drawable отображается на устройстве неправильно?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

Сабж. Почему мой drawable на устройстве выглядит иначе (Круг в центре. Линии это другие ресурсы) ?

Код ресурса :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
            <size android:height="25dp" android:width="25dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FF000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center"  >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
            <size android:height="5dp" android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Код лэйаута :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill_vertical"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:minWidth="2dp" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill_vertical"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:minWidth="2dp" />

    </GridLayout>


    <ImageView android:layout_column="1" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Назвваиен" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Назвваиен" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Назвваиен" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

В студии

[image: В студии]

На устройстве

[image: На устройстве]

В ресурсах

[image: В ресурсах]

Comment: Тот круг что по центру почему то на устройстве не центрируется, а заполняет весь drawable.

Comment: это особенность `Drawable layer-list` с `Shape`... в свое время решил проблему через `Bitmap` с `Gravity`

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich неприятная особенность. Пока что на вот таком костыле         `android:top="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"`

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:height="25dp" android:width="25dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FF000000"/>
            <padding android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
            <size android:height="5dp" android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```